# Diferencias HttpRequest y httpRequestBase

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Desde el controlador la clase controller obtengo la propiedad `Request` y desde `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request` pero no entiendo la utilidad:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpRequestBase base = Request;
        HttpRequest req = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Entre ellas también figura `HttpContext` y `HttpContextBase`

Comment: simplemente es una forma de llegar a lo mismo. El controlador tiene esa propiedad definida para su clase ... esta misma propiedad finalmente hace referencia a la petición actual de la instancia actual de tu aplicación

Comment: otra cosa, a base le puedes asignar otro tipo de request porque es tipo que estas asignando implementa a base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) está presente en las clases [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) y [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.aspx) como una propiedad GET-only. De forma similar, la mayoría de sus propiedades también son GET-only (ver 1). Esta clase es utilizada por las páginas ASP.NET para obtener información acerca de la solicitud http entrante, p. Leer el IP del cliente, cookies, la cadena de consulta, etc. Es importante saber que es parte de la "Vieja" System.Web Asamblea, que ha estado alrededor desde. NET 1.1

[HttpRequestMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.aspx), por otro lado, es nuevo en .NET 4.5. Es parte de [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.aspx). Puede ser utilizado por clientes y servicios para crear, enviar y recibir solicitudes y respuestas a través de HTTP. Reemplaza HttpWebRequest, que es obsoleto en .NET 4.5

En HttpRequestBase y HttpRequestWrapper, lo mejor que puedo hacer es citar sólo los [documentos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestwrapper.aspx)

> La clase HttpRequestWrapper se deriva de la clase HttpRequestBase y
>   sirve como un contenedor para la clase HttpRequest. Esta clase expone
>   la funcionalidad de la clase HttpRequest y expone el tipo de
>   HttpRequestBase. La clase HttpRequestBase le permite reemplazar la
>   implementación original de la clase HttpRequest en su aplicación con
>   una implementación personalizada, como cuando realiza pruebas de
>   unidad fuera de ASP.NET